# Kate pate wont load KDE 4.13

Tags: python, kde-plasma, kate

Unsure if the upgrade to KDE 4.13(I am on beta 3) has caused something new to be done to load kate python plugins.

I have done the usual linking

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kate_plugins $(kde4-config --localprefix)/share/apps/kate/pate
```

And from this [kate thread](http://kate-editor.org/2013/05/31/a-rich-python-console-and-more-in-kate-editor/) noticed this comment

> You have a simple installation guide here (Building Kate from
>   Sources):
>
> http://kate-editor.org/get-it/
>
> After it only you have to add the kate.so to the python path…

So i have done that.

```
root@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:/usr/lib/python2.7# export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKate4/kate.so
```

The Pate engine still will not load any suggestions?

Comment: This might be totally useless, but shouldn't you be adding a FOLDER to your PYTHONPATH and not the .so file? `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyKate4/`

Comment: Could you ask on kwrite-devel@kde.org for help?